# Masonry sometimes not displaying content properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, masonry

I am creating a website and I want to use Masonry there. https://masonry.desandro.com
I am facing a problem where I have absolutely no idea where it might come from.

The masonry is working fine when I am logged in. As soon as I log out it seems like the jquery code is not used.

I already checked the html file and used an diff checker too. 
I couldn't find a reason for the problem. No matter if logged in or logged out the selector path for the container is the same.
Deleting certain parts of my index.html and moving the script to call it (see code below) causes the masonry to work not even when I am logged in. (So neither when  logged in or logged out then.)

I have no idea where and what could cause the error.
So I don't know which code to provide.
I would really appreciate someone telling me where and what the error should/could be located it. 
I am sorry for the rather poor description.
I have never worked with jquery before and only had experience with html, css and javascript.

```
<script>
$('#boxwebpart1817').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.message',
  gutter: 50,
  isFitWidth: true
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is the site available online?

Comment: It is. https://test.vereinonline.org/HTC_Uhlenhorst/

Comment: Have you tried debugging the error shown in the console? SliderScript.js, line #33

Comment: No. To be honest I don't know how/what to do there...

Comment: Any screenshot of how the page looks when you are logged in?

Comment: The slider is also being showed when you are logged in and the error is also shown when you are logged in. So I thought it cannot be the reason. Am I wrong?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/BPnkkPP

Comment: I've just disabled the slider code and the masonry layout is still broken, so I guess, yes.

Comment: It seems that the markup is different when you are logged in. There is a section (Hello Benedikt), which might interfere with the masonry layout init probably?

Comment: I think I found the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

When the page is loaded, the `<div class="webpartcontentorot">` element is placed inside another `<div>`. If you move the `<div class="webpartcontentorot">` element outside this `<div>` and rerun the Masonry init script, the layout will be displayed correctly.

Now, I am not sure how you've integrated the Masonry section into this website or how the backend works, but you might want to check out this detail and try to figure out the root of the problem.

[image]

*This is the page on the first load*

[image]

*I move the section outside the div, via the DevTools*

[image]

*I execute the Masonry init script, and the layout works perfectly*